# Developing WebGIS application with geoserver+geoext+postgresql vs geoserver+leaflet+postgresql?

Tags: gis, geoserver, qgis

I need to build a small Web GIS application, where the end user can:
1. upload a polygonal shapefile
2. the shapefile goes to a backend database (may be postgresql)
3. A spatial operation (overlay) is performed with existing 3 layers (already loaded to postgresql) and the result is returned like: the uploaded file falls within AAA layer (shapefile stored in postgresql) and is intersected with abc files, its total area is BBB etc

Then the user upload another polygonal shapefile, 
1. it gets uploaded to the database (I dont know if this is required step or can be skipped)
2. generate summary statistics on one column and present result in the form of a chart

Then the user upload a point layer shapefile
1. system generate a service area map based on the location of points

Please advise what open source tools can be best for me to start.

I was thinking to go with geoserver, geoext, and postgresql. Is that a good commbination. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the web mapping applications consist of two parts; client side and server side.

At server side part, you need a map sever like ArcGIS server or geoserver and a database with ability for storing, handling, and manipulating spatial data like postGIS. PostGIS provides tons of useful spatial function that you can use in your spatial analyses.

At client side part, you can use the ready-to-use tools like geoExt if you don't have enough time to develop your application or you don't have enough skill to create a web application from start. But if you have enough skill in designing and developing the responsive web application, you can use Bootstrap or React and also use openlayers or leaflet to visualizing and handling spatial data on the web pages.